# Deploy WCF Service in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, wcf, .net-core, deployment

How to deploy .NET Core WCF service to Azure?

I am expecting step by step Azure deployment of .NET Core WCF service...

I have .NET Core WCF service and I want it to deploy it in Azure. First of all - is that possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are several main steps to deploy WCF service to Azure:

1. Create a windows Azure account and install windows Azure SDK in your local.
2. Create a new windows Azure cloud service project and put your WCF service in it.
3. Log in the Windows Azure account and open the windows Azure portal to create a new cloud service.
4. Click `upload a new production deployment` to upload your WCF service in cloud service and wait for deployment.

And then you will get a WCF service deployed in Azure. The article below shows more detailed steps to depoly the service.

[Deploying A WCF Service On Windows Azure](https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/08/03/deploying-a-wcf-service-on-windows-azure/)

Hope it helps.